# Method is not changing the value globally but only inside method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Declare variables

```
    public Text economyWorth;
    public int economy_worth;

    public int Tax_amount;
    public Text TaxAmount;

    public int population;
    public Text pop;
```

Initialise values in `void start()`

```
        economy_worth = 900000;
        economyWorth.text = economy_worth.ToString();
        economyWorth = GetComponent<Text>();

        Tax_amount = (int)(0.8 * population);
        TaxAmount.text = Tax_amount.ToString();
        TaxAmount = GetComponent<Text>();

        population = 160000;
        pop.text = population.ToString();
        pop = GetComponent<Text>();
```

Written a Method to add `Tax_amount` in `economy_worth`

```
    public void CollectTax()
    {
        if (Tax_amount == (int)(0.8 * population))
        {
            Debug.Log("Economy before collection" + economy_worth);
            Debug.Log("Tax before collection" + Tax_amount);
            economy_worth += Tax_amount;
            Tax_amount = 0;
            Debug.Log("Economy after collection" + economy_worth);
            Debug.Log("Tax after collection" + Tax_amount);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Tax not collected");
        }
    }
```

Method does the task what it is made for. `Tax_amount` adds to `economy_worth` shows by `Debug.Log(economy_worth)`
[Economy_worth shows updated inside function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui7DU.png)
But this value stays here in this method and `Debug.Log()` and not updated globally where I'm displaying the `Economy_worth`
[economy_worth not updated globally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me941.png)

CAN ANYONE TELL ME WHAT I AM MISSING?

MY WHOLE CODE IS BELOW:

```
public class Game_Manager : MonoBehaviour
{   //COVID HOSPITAL
    public Text CovidPT;
    public Text CovidHealth;
    public int Covid_PT;
    public string covid_health;

    //NATIONAL BANK
    public Text economyWorth;
    public Text economyHealth;
    public int economy_worth;
    public string economy_health;

    //SOCIETY OFFICE / RESTRICTION
    public Text restriction;
    public string restrc;

    //MARKET
    public Text CovidBudget;
    public int Covid_Budget;

    //POPULATION/RESIDENTIAL AREA
    public int population;
    public Text pop;
    public string ph;
    public Text phealth;

    //TAX COLLECTION
    public int Tax_amount;
    public Text TaxAmount;

    //OVERALL PERFORMANCE
    public string performance;
    public Text performancehealth;

    //VENTILATOR PURCHASE
    public Text vCount;
    public Text vCost;
    public int vCountAmount;
    public int totalCost12;
    public int valueCopy;

    //VACCINE PURCHASE
    public Text vacCount;
    public Text vacCost;
    public int vacCountAmount;
    public int totalCostVac;

    //MASK PURCHASE
    public Text maskCount;
    public Text maskCost;
    public int maskCountAmount;
    public int totalCostMask;

    //SHELTER PURCHASE
    public Text shelterCount;
    public Text shelterCost;
    public int shelterCountAmount;
    public int totalCostShelter;



    void Start()
    {
        
        //COVID PATEINTS
        Covid_PT = 9000;
        CovidPT.text = Covid_PT.ToString();
     //   CovidPT = GetComponent<Text>();
        if (Covid_PT < 8000)
        {
            covid_health = "Good";
            CovidHealth.text = covid_health.ToString();
     //       CovidHealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
        if (Covid_PT > 8100 || Covid_PT < 12100)
        {
            covid_health = "Bad";
            CovidHealth.text = covid_health.ToString();
     //       CovidHealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
            if (Covid_PT > 12100)
        {
            covid_health = "Worst";
            CovidHealth.text = covid_health.ToString();
    //        CovidHealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }

        //NATIONAL BANK
       // economy_worth = 900000;
        economyWorth.text = economy_worth.ToString();
       // economyWorth = GetComponent<Text>();

        if (economy_worth > 1000000)
        {
            economy_health = "Excellent";
            economyHealth.text = economy_health.ToString();
           // economyHealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
        if (economy_worth > 800000)
        {
            economy_health = "Good";
            economyHealth.text = economy_health.ToString();
           // economyHealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
            if (economy_worth < 800000)
        {
            economy_health = "Bad";
            economyHealth.text = economy_health.ToString();
           // economyHealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }

        //RESTRICTION
        restrc = " Mild Lockdown";
        restriction.text = restrc.ToString();
 //       restriction = GetComponent<Text>();


        //MARKET
        Covid_Budget = (int)(0.01 * economy_worth);
        CovidBudget.text = Covid_Budget.ToString();
     //   CovidBudget = GetComponent<Text>();

        //POPULATION / RESIDENTIAL AREA
        population = 160000;
        pop.text = population.ToString();
     //   pop = GetComponent<Text>();

        if (population < 160000)
        {
            ph = "Bad Decrease";
            phealth.text = ph.ToString();
         //   phealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
        if (population >= 160000)
        {
            ph = "Mild Decrease";
            phealth.text = ph.ToString();
         //   phealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
            if (population >= 200000)
        {
            ph = "No Decrease";
            phealth.text = ph.ToString();
        //    phealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }

        //TAX COLLECTION
        Tax_amount = (int)(0.8 * population);
        TaxAmount.text = Tax_amount.ToString();
        //TaxAmount = GetComponent<Text>();

        //PERFORMANCE  HEALTH      
        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Excellent";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
         //   performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Worst";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
          //  performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Good";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
          //  performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
        //    performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Satisfactroy";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
           // performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //     performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Satisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
        //    performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
        //    performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //     performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Good";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
        //    performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Satisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //     performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //    performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //     performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
     //       performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
     //       performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Worst";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
    //        performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Worst";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
     //       performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //     performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //     performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
        //    performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Worst";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //     performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
     //       performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Worst";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
     //       performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Worst";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
     //       performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
        {
            performance = "Not Sure";
            performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }


        //VENTILATOR PURCHASE
      //  vCount = GetComponent<Text>();
       // vCost = GetComponent<Text>();

        //VACCINE PURCHASE
      //  vacCount = GetComponent<Text>();
      //  vacCost = GetComponent<Text>();

        //MASK PURCHASE
      //  maskCount = GetComponent<Text>();
      //  maskCost = GetComponent<Text>();

        //SHELTER PURCHASE
      //  shelterCount = GetComponent<Text>();
      //  shelterCost = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // M    E    T    H    O    D   S

    //VENTILATOR PURCHASE
    public void AddCount()
    {
        vCountAmount++;
        vCount = GetComponent<Text>();
        vCount.text = vCountAmount.ToString();
        Debug.Log("Num of vents: " + vCountAmount);
    }
    public void AddPrice()
    {
        //valueCopy = 1800;
        totalCost12 += 1800;
        
      

        vCost = GetComponent<Text>();
        vCost.text = totalCost12.ToString();
        Debug.Log("total cost is: " + totalCost12);
       
    }

    public void SubtractCount()
    {
        if (vCountAmount >= 1)
        {
            vCountAmount -= 1;
            vCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            vCount.text = vCountAmount.ToString();
            Debug.Log(vCountAmount);
        }
        else
        {
            vCountAmount = 0;
            vCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            vCount.text = vCountAmount.ToString();
        }
    }

    public void SubtractPrice()
    {
        Debug.Log("subtraction is occuring");
        if (totalCost12 >= 1800)
        {
            totalCost12 -= 1800;
            vCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            vCost.text = totalCost12.ToString();


            Debug.Log(totalCost12);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("majamaja");
            totalCost12 = 0;
            vCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            vCost.text = totalCost12.ToString();
        }
    }

    public void PurchaseVent()
    {
      //  Debug.Log("value copy" +valueCopy);
        Debug.Log("before logic total cost is " + totalCost12);
        economy_worth -= totalCost12;
        

        Debug.Log("Economy after purchase" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("total cost is " + totalCost12);

        Covid_PT -= vCountAmount * 60;
        Debug.Log("Pateints after purchase" + Covid_PT);
        Debug.Log("Num of vents: " + vCountAmount);
    }

    //VACCINE PURCHASE
    public void AddCountVac()
    {
        vacCountAmount += 4;
        vacCount = GetComponent<Text>();
        vacCount.text = vacCountAmount.ToString();
        Debug.Log("Num of vaccines: " + vacCountAmount);
    }
    public void AddVaccine()
    {
        totalCostVac += 80 * 4;
        vacCost = GetComponent<Text>();
        vacCost.text = totalCostVac.ToString();
        Debug.Log("total cost is " + totalCostVac);
    }
    public void SubtractCountVac()
    {
        if (vacCountAmount >= 4)
        {
            vacCountAmount -= 4;
            vacCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            vacCount.text = vacCountAmount.ToString();
            Debug.Log("Num of vaccines: " + vacCountAmount);
        }
        else
        {
            vacCountAmount = 0;
            vacCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            vacCount.text = vacCountAmount.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void SubtractVaccine()
    {
        if (totalCostVac >= 80 * 4)
        {
            totalCostVac -= 80 * 4;
            vacCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            vacCost.text = totalCostVac.ToString();
            Debug.Log("total cost is " + totalCostVac);
        }
        else
        {
            totalCostVac = 0;
            vacCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            vacCost.text = totalCostVac.ToString();
        }
    }

    public void PurchaceVaccines()
    {
        Debug.Log("before logic total cost is " + totalCostVac);
        economy_worth -= totalCostVac;
        Debug.Log(economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("total cost is " + totalCostVac);

        Covid_PT -= vacCountAmount * 6 / 4;
        Debug.Log(Covid_PT);
        Debug.Log("Num of vaccines: " + vacCountAmount);
    }
    //MASK PURCHASE
    public void AddCountMask()
    {
        maskCountAmount += 50;
        maskCount = GetComponent<Text>();
        maskCount.text = maskCountAmount.ToString();
        Debug.Log(maskCountAmount);
    }
    public void Addmask()
    {
        totalCostMask += 5 * 50;
        maskCost = GetComponent<Text>();
        maskCost.text = totalCostMask.ToString();
        Debug.Log(totalCostMask);
    }
    public void SubtractCountMask()
    {
        if (maskCountAmount >= 50)
        {
            maskCountAmount -= 50;
            maskCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            maskCount.text = maskCountAmount.ToString();
            Debug.Log(maskCountAmount);

        }
        else
        {
            maskCountAmount = 0;
            maskCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            maskCount.text = maskCountAmount.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void Subtractmask()
    {
        if (totalCostMask >= 5 * 50)
        {
            totalCostMask -= 5 * 50;
            maskCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            maskCost.text = totalCostMask.ToString();
            Debug.Log(totalCostMask);

        }
        else
        {
            totalCostMask = 0;
            maskCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            maskCost.text = totalCostMask.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void PurchaceMasks()
    {
        Debug.Log("before logic total cost is " + totalCostMask);
        economy_worth -= totalCostMask;
        Debug.Log(economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("total cost is " + totalCostMask);

        Covid_PT -= maskCountAmount * 2 / 50;
        Debug.Log(Covid_PT);
        Debug.Log("Num of vaccines: " + maskCountAmount);
    }
    //SHELTER PURCHASE
    public void AddCountShelter()
    {
        shelterCountAmount++;
        shelterCount = GetComponent<Text>();
        shelterCount.text = shelterCountAmount.ToString();
        Debug.Log(shelterCountAmount);
    }
    public void Addshelter()
    {
        totalCostShelter += 1500;
        shelterCost = GetComponent<Text>();
        shelterCost.text = totalCostShelter.ToString();
        Debug.Log(totalCostShelter);
    }
    public void SubtractCountShelter()
    {
        if (shelterCountAmount >= 1)
        {
            shelterCountAmount -= 1;
            shelterCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            shelterCount.text = shelterCountAmount.ToString();
            Debug.Log(shelterCountAmount);
        }
        else
        {
            shelterCountAmount = 0;
            shelterCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            shelterCount.text = shelterCountAmount.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void Subtractshelter()
    {
        if (totalCostShelter >= 1500)
        {
            totalCostShelter -= 1500;
            shelterCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            shelterCost.text = totalCostShelter.ToString();
            Debug.Log(totalCostShelter);
        }
        else
        {
            totalCostShelter = 0;
            shelterCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            shelterCost.text = totalCostShelter.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void PurchaceShelter()
    {
        Debug.Log("before logic total cost is " + totalCostShelter);
        economy_worth -= totalCostShelter;
        Debug.Log(economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("total cost is " + totalCostShelter);

        Covid_PT -= shelterCountAmount * 80;
        Debug.Log(Covid_PT);
        Debug.Log("Num of vaccines: " + shelterCountAmount);
    }
    //RESTRICTION

    public void curfew()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth before curfew" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Pateints before curfew" + Covid_PT);
        economy_worth -= 50;        
        Invoke("curfew", 1.0f);
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth after curfew" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Patients after curfew" + Covid_PT);
    }
    public void strict()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth before strict lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Pateints before strict lockdown" + Covid_PT);
        economy_worth -= 40;
        Covid_PT++;
        Invoke("strict", 1.0f);
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth after strict lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Patients after strict lockdown" + Covid_PT);
    }
    public void mild()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth before mild lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Pateints before mild lockdown" + Covid_PT);
        economy_worth -= 30;
        Covid_PT += 2;
        Invoke("mild", 1.0f);
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth after mild lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Patients after mild lockdown" + Covid_PT);
    }
    public void smart()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth before smart lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Pateints before smart lockdown" + Covid_PT);
        economy_worth -= 15;
        Covid_PT += 3;
        Invoke("smart", 1.0f);
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth after smart lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Patients after smart lockdown" + Covid_PT);
    }
    public void NoLockdown()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth before No lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Pateints before No lockdown" + Covid_PT);
        economy_worth -= 8;
        Covid_PT += 5;
        Invoke("NoLockdown", 1.0f);
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth after No lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Patients after No lockdown" + Covid_PT);
    }
    //TAX COLLECTION
    
    public void CollectTax()
    {
        
        if (Tax_amount == (int)(0.8 * population))
        {
            Debug.Log("Economy before collection: " + economy_worth);
            Debug.Log("Tax before collection: " + Tax_amount);
            economy_worth += Tax_amount;
//            economyWorth.text = economy_worth.ToString();
           // economyWorth = GetComponent<Text>();
            Tax_amount = 0;
            Debug.Log("Economy after collection: " + economy_worth);
            Debug.Log("Tax after collection: " + Tax_amount);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Tax not collected");
        }
    }
    // S T O R E
    public void item_1()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy before Purchase" + economy_worth);
        economy_worth += 60000;
        Debug.Log("Economy after Purchase" + economy_worth);
    }
    public void item_2()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy before Purchase" + economy_worth);
        economy_worth += 30000;
        Debug.Log("Economy after Purchase" + economy_worth);
    }
    public void item_3()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy before Purchase" + economy_worth);
        economy_worth += 20000;
        Debug.Log("Economy after Purchase" + economy_worth);
    }
    public void item_4()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy before Purchase" + economy_worth);
        economy_worth += 10000;
        Debug.Log("Economy after Purchase" + economy_worth);
    }


    void Update()
    {  //MARKET
       //  Covid_Budget = (int)(0.01 * economy_worth);
       //  CovidBudget.text = Covid_Budget.ToString();
       // CovidBudget = GetComponent<Text>();

        //Debug.Log(totalCost12.ToString());
    }
    
    public void Awake()
    {   //NATIONAL BANK
        economy_worth = 900000;
        //Covid
        Covid_PT = 9000;
        //POPULATION
        population = 160000;
        //TAX COLLECTION
        Tax_amount = (int)(0.8 * population);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the `economyWorth.text` again some where? You update the variable, but not the display.

Comment: how to update the display?
like do i need to write `economyWorth.text = economy_worth.ToString();` in my method `CollectTax`?
But this practice throws an error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Game_Manager.CollectTax ()

Comment: thats because of this like `economyWorth = GetComponent<Text>();` remove it to not set a new component on you variable.

Comment: I have removed all `GetComponent<Text>();` but still facing null error.

Comment: Please update your question and let us see

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing what it is supposed to. To update the text on the UI, you need to set `economy_worth` and `TaxAmount` 's `.text` property like you do in `Start()`.

PS: you should remove all lines with `GetComponent<Text>();` in `Start()`

Comment: You mean to say I should write `economyWorth.text = economy_worth.ToString();` in my method `CollectTax()`?

actually I did it, whenever I write this in any methods below it throws me an error:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Game_Manager.CollectTax ()

Comment: Yeah, and that is why I tell you to remove the GetComponent<Text>(). This will return a component, but you have already assigned the values (since you are using them in `Start()`, and are overriding them with `null`

Comment: No bro, I have commented all `GetComponent<Text>()` in `Start()` but still the line `economyWorth.text = economy_worth.ToString();` in `CollectTax()` throws the same error.

Comment: and you dont get an error in  `Start()` when setting `economyWorth.text`?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference whether I write `.text` in `start()` or not. My problem was that my text is not being updated in UI. For that, as you suggested, I wrote `economyWorth.text = economy_worth.ToString();` in my method `CollectTax()`.
But it throws Null error. Then you asked me to remove all `.test`. from `start()`. I removed/commented it but the error problem remains.

Comment: It does. If you are able to set it in `Start()`, but are not able to set it later, it means the value of the `Text` instance has been modified. The only place I see you modify that is in `Start()`. That is why I suggested removing the assignments, because I am *sure* that they are what override the values with `null` or at least faulty values.

Comment: Yes If I write `GetComponent<Text>()` in `start()` everything works fine. But then If I add `.ToString()` in my method it throws null error. Whether I write `GetComponent<Text>()` in `start()` or not, writing `.ToString()` in method `CollectTax();` throws error.

Now, I have removed all `GetComponent<Text>()` from `start()` and methods below. Still i'm facing null error, Why?

Comment: Could you show the code you have as of now?

Comment: okay, I've added it in the end please check.

Comment: `economyWorth.text = economy_worth.ToString();`. Why is this commented out? Does this throw an error? Also, does any line at `Start()` also throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

Part of your issue is that you are assigning the *same* text object to all of your text variables (if any at all). GetComponent() will find the first component on the current GameObject that matches the type Text. It has no way of knowing that you want a specific one. If the text boxes are not components of the same GameObject that this script is on, they'll all get null.

Since these are public fields you can set them by dragging them in through the editor. If you have done this, you do not need to set them via GetComponent at all.
Otherwise, you can retrieve the GameObject of the text box by name, and get that specific component, such as:

```
void Start()
{
    // Other stuff...
    economyText = GameObject.Find("economyText").GetComponent<Text>(); // Assuming that the name of the game object is also economyText, otherwise update to match
}
```

Secondly, as @berlm pointed out, you can't just link the text to a value variable and expect it to update each time the variable updates. You have to tell Unity each time you want it to update the text.

```
economyWorth.text = economy_worth.ToString();
```

If you don't want to have to call this manually each time you set the value of economy_worth (which is bad naming convention by the way) you could make it a property and update the text in the setter like:

```
private int _economyWorth;
public int EconomyWorth 
{
    get 
    {
        return _economyWorth;
    }
    set
    {
        _economyWorth = value;
        economyText.text = value.ToString();
    }
}
```